# How do I control the date format submitted on Firefox?

Tags: jquery, firefox, datepicker, date-format

This is specific to Firefox v 32.0.3 on Mac 10.9.5 with jQuery 1.8.2.  I have the following HTML element on my page

```
<input id="myDate" name="myDate" placeholder="My Date" value="" type="date">
```

On Firefox, I need to invoke the following jQuery to get the picker to render properly …

```
$("#myDate").datepicker({ format: "mm-dd-yyyy", altFormat: "mm-dd-yyyy" });
```

However, when I submit my form, the date is submitted in the format mm/dd/yyyy, and I can’t figure out why.  Any ideas how I can control (on Firefox) how the format of how the date gets submitted?  It would be nice if there were a cross-browser solution to this, but I’ll start with the basics.

Comment: As you're using `DatePicker`, have you tried to use a regular `input type text` instead?

Comment: I should have mentioned I only call the jQuery date picker where the 'type="date"' isn't supported.